# Django Custom Permission method or decorator

Tags: django, django-permissions

I am many views and more than one user type. I want some views that can be seen by specific user types and other users cant see this.

For example, only company see this views and for this i did that like this below:

```
@login_required
def only_company_can_view(request):
    if not Company.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).exists():
        return HttpResponse('Permission Denied. Only Company can see this')

    # > rest of the logic
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

and above this working very well and solves my problem but i don't like this. coz, i don't want to write every time for the rest of the views for the company related views.

So i am finding a solution so that i can use decorator or something else that are best practice

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the logic in a decorator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from functools import wraps

def requires_company(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Company.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).exists():    
            raise PermissionDenied
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _view
```

Then you use the decorator with:

```
@login_required
@requires_company
def only_company_can_view(request):
    # … rest of the logic …
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

Comment: @howrecepes: sorry there was still a typo: forgot to pass the `request` parameter explicitly because we need this for `request.user.id`.